# Layout issue in Android Studio for large and normal screens

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout, screen

In my res folder I have: activity_main.xml in the layout folder (so the default one), the same file in the layout-large folder and in the layout-normal folder.

I set the layout I want in the preview of an Samsung Galaxy S5 (so a large screen) and then I run the AVD: here the layout is different. There's an image positioned differently. On the contrary this doesn't happen when I run the app on a normal screen.

```
Here's the activity_main.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/sfondo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginTop="-150dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/tronco1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="370dp"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:src="@drawable/titolo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:src="@drawable/play_h"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:src="@drawable/options_h"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:src="@drawable/score_h"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:src="@drawable/removeads_h"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

### in your java file:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager windowmanager = (WindowManager)  getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowmanager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);


int deviceWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int deviceHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

FrameLayout.LayoutParams frm = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)findViewById(R.id.trump_center_frame).getLayoutParams();


 frm.width = get_screen_width(710);
 frm.height = get_screen_height(270);
 frm.bottomMargin = get_screen_height(80);
 frm.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;


 TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.trump_title);

 frm = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)title.getLayoutParams();//here title is in frame layout
frm.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
 frm.topMargin = get_screen_height(24);
```

### ## use above mentioned method for all view##

### create method

```
private int get_screen_width(int w) {
    return deviceWidth * w / 720;// dimention(720)(width) of screen in which you set layout
}

private int get_screen_height(int h) {
    return deviceHeight * h / 1280;// dimention(1280)(height) of screen in which you set layout
}
```