# Android Studio drawable image doesn't appear on physical device

Tags: java, android, android-studio

There's no need of the code. I've just opened a new project and added an ImageView with an image inside. Then I've run the app on the emulator and it appears, while the screen is completely white on the physical device.

Then I tried with another image and this one appears instead.

The device is a Samsung Core Pro.
The images are .png and the one that doesn't appear is 465 width x 2970 height, while the other is 1920 x 1280, if it can help.

Here's the log message: W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (698x4455, max=4096x4096)

Thanks

Comment: And the resolution of the one that appears is .... ?

Comment: Is there any relevant log in the logcat?

Comment: edited with the logs

Comment: Exactly what I suspected. First, there's no need to have such a huge image. But even if you do, place it in the appropriate drawable folder (xxhdpi at least) otherwise the image will be upscaled via the density factor which is 1.5 in your current case.

Comment: `Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture `. So you knew already.

Comment: Yes but in the log there's written 698x4455 while my image is 465x2970, but you said it automatically scales it to 1.5

Comment: Could you please check out this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947533/layout-issue-in-android-studio-for-large-and-normal-screens

Comment: @AlessandroGiovagnoli "...the image will be upscaled via the density factor..." means it will be multiplied with 1.5 resulting 698x4455.